# Hadoop Insert Without Select Clause

Tags: java, hadoop, hive

I'm New to Hadoop,i need to insert a record in a Table,When i search for syntax, every where the insert statement has values from select statement.

Is there a way to insert simple values with out Select statement?

Regards,
Sathish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off I am guessing by the tag we are talking about HIVE.

When you are really using hive, you would never have a reason to add entries one at a time.

Easiest way to do this I think is to first create a CSV file with your data.

```
sample.csv
Dan,50
Dave,20
Sam,30
```

Then we place the file in hdfs

```
hadoop fs -copyFromLocal ./sample.csv /user/me/sample.csv
```

Now we go into hive and create our table with our data.

```
$ hive
hive> Create EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS sample(NAME STRING, Grade int)
hive> ROW FORMATED DELIMITED FILED TERMINATED BY ','
hive> STORED AS TEXTFILE location '/user/me/sample.csv';
```

Comment: Thanks, Now only i'm able to Understand about HIVE, which is not for simple SQL queries. I've one more doubt, I've created csv & inserted, what if i add few more rows & load it again. Whether the records will be overridden.

Comment: CREATE ETERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS

This means that if you rerun the code if the table exists it will do nothing. 

You can first do hive>drop sample; and then rerun it with your new file.

Comment: Long live the table of ETERNITY! ("external") ;)